# Remove double quotes from athena query results

Tags: java, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a athena table with an int column format as

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `events`(
  `build` string, 
  `event_ts` bigint
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'xyz'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='events', 
  'averageRecordSize'='166', 
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='9569916', 
  'recordCount'='892536278576', 
  'sizeKey'='141488304366761', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

When i query that table it always returns results wrapped in double quotes for each column build or event_ts. There are no quotes in the original data.

Output from select * in java and when downloaded from athena is

```
"build1", "1234314"
"build2", "1231231"
```

Can someone advise how to remove these double quotes in query results  without changing these table formats or replacing the quotes in the application ?

Comment: Set table Serde parameters with quoteChar= " and if your data has escape characters to point literal " value, then set escapeChar=\ as well. Ex: WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'escapeChar'='\\', 
  'quoteChar'='\"')