# Querying Athena from Python returns columns with double quotes

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-athena

Similar issue as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68581734/remove-double-quotes-from-athena-query-results).
This is the code I use for the boto3 `start_query_execution`:

```
response = client.start_query_execution(
         QueryString=sql,
         ResultConfiguration={
             'OutputLocation': f'<S3 LOCATION>',
            'EncryptionConfiguration': {
                 'EncryptionOption': 'SSE_S3'
             }
         }
     )
```

The Athena table has some float columns and some string columns.

When I open the CSV file generated in the S3 location in Excel, the data looks fine. **EDIT: opening it in Notepad has shown that the columns are indeed actually wrapped in double quotes. So the issue is querying from boto3 is returning a csv with double quotes for some reason. If I use pyathena PandasCursor to convert to dataframe then to CSV again, no issues but this will take much longer than just directly getting CSV from the query.**

However, when I query in Athena for the resulting table, all of the string columns has double quotes surrounding it, and all of the float columns are empty.

| str_column1 | float_column | str_column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "example" |  | "example2" |

I suspected it was a DDL issue, this is what i see when i do `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `tbl` (
  `str_column1` string, 
  `float_column` float, 
  `str_column2` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '<S3 LOCATION>'
```

I tried deleting and re-creating table using OpenCSVSerde, which doesnt work as I have non-string columns. I tried adding WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('escapeChar'='\', 'quoteChar'='"') which just made all of the values squeeze into the first column and all the other columns became blank.

Comment: You have to show your CSV file.

Comment: @Marcin I opened the CSV file in notepad instead of excel and indeed the CSV generated had double quotes wrapped around each column. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, had to change the table DDL.

Changed to OpenCSVSerde but added in the 'WITH SERDEPROPERTIES' to delimit instead of `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` and it worked. The caveat is that for your float columns, you will not be able to have null values in them. Null values in string columns are fine.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `tbl` (
  `str_column1` string, 
  `float_column` float, 
  `str_column2` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'separatorChar'=',')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  '<S3 LOCATION>'
```